# How to retrieve a list of objects from a different table in same model?

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, hibernate

I have two models, both of them are using hibernate and uses mySQL, they have a ManyToOne relationship, I am using AngularJS to display the view. I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve a list of objects from TraineeStatus model and store it in Trainee model?

TraineeStatus.java

```
@Entity
public class Trainees {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int traineesID;
    @ManyToOne
    private Technologies technologies;
    @ManyToOne
    private TraineeStatus traineestatus;
    private int customersID;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String phoneDetails;
    private String email;

    public Trainees(){

    }

    public Trainees(String name, String surname, String phoneDetails, String email, int id, Technologies technologies, TraineeStatus traineestatus, int customersID) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneDetails = phoneDetails;
        this.technologies = technologies;
        this.traineestatus = traineestatus;
        this.customersID = customersID;
    }
//getters and setters
```

TraineeStatus.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="traineeStatus")
public class TraineeStatus {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int traineeStatusId;
    private String value;

    public TraineeStatus(){

    }
```

My goal is to retrieve an array of objects from TraineeStatus with id and value inside the object and the use it in my Trainees model. Is it possible to do it? Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
@Entity
@Table(name="traineeStatus")
public class TraineeStatus {


   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "traineestatus")
   private List<Trainees> orderItems;

   ...

   // GETTERS and SETTERS

}
```

Comment: Good idea thank, just I need opposite, I need to retrieve List of TraineeStatuses, I have implemented @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "traineestatus")
    private List<TraineeStatus> traineestatus; but it says that Target entity is not defined.

Comment: /@ManyToOne annotation can't be applied to List field, if you have "one to many" association use @OneToMany annnotation

Comment: the logic I have is that one or more trainees can have only one status, the controller is sitting on trainees model, so I can retrieve data from traineestatus model, only from trainee, I thought it is possible to retrieve whole table in trainee model instead of creating another controller for traineestatus model.

Comment: So, do you want to retrieve ALL existing statuses from TraineeStatus table using Trainees entity only?

Comment: Something like that. I am hoping that is possible :) There is only 3 statuses with id and value, I am hoping I wont need to create another controler and a view for it and I could just simply retrieve those 3 values inside Trainee model and use same controler as Trainee is using to pass it to the view.

Comment: Usually, the logic for work with DB incapsulated in DAO layer and these problems do not arise.  Imho, you approach is antipattern. Nonetheless, you can use @Formula annotation to do it, but it is not good idea.